# Month on month values in django query

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-annotate

I have an annotation like this: which displays the month wise count of a field

```
bar = Foo.objects.annotate(
    item_count=Count('item')
).order_by('-item_month', '-item_year')
```

and this produces output like this:
[html render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtCmg.jpg)

I would like to show the change in item_count when compared with the previous month item_count for each month (except the first month). How could I achieve this using annotations or do I need to use pandas?

Thanks

Edit:
In SQL this becomes easy with LAG function, which is similar to

```
SELECT item_month, item_year, COUNT(item),
LAG(COUNT(item)) OVER (ORDER BY item_month, item_year)
FROM Foo 
GROUP BY item_month, item_year
```

(PS: item_month and item_year are date fields)

Do Django ORM have similar to LAG in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these types of Query you need to use Window functions in django Orm

For Lag you can take the help of

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/database-functions/#lag

Working Query in Orm will look like this :

#models.py

```
class Review(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='review_user', db_index=True)
    review_text = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    rating = models.SmallIntegerField(
        validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(10),
            MinValueValidator(1),
        ],
    )
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    review_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_index=True)
```

This is just a dummy table to show you the use case of `Lag` and `Window` function in django
Because examples are not available for Lag function on Django Docs.

```
from django.db.models.functions import Lag, ExtractYear
from django.db.models import F, Window

print(Review.objects.filter().annotate(
        num_likes=Count('likereview_review')
    ).annotate(item_count_lag=Window(expression=Lag(expression=F('num_likes')),order_by=ExtractYear('date_added').asc())).order_by('-num_likes').distinct().query)
```

Query will look like

```
SELECT DISTINCT `temp_view_review`.`user_id`, `temp_view_review`.`review_text`, `temp_view_review`.`rating`, `temp_view_review`.`date_added`, `temp_view_review`.`review_id`, COUNT(`temp_view_likereview`.`id`) AS `num_likes`, LAG(COUNT(`temp_view_likereview`.`id`), 1) OVER (ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM `temp_view_review`.`date_added`) ASC) AS `item_count_lag` FROM `temp_view_review` LEFT OUTER JOIN `temp_view_likereview` ON (`temp_view_review`.`review_id` = `temp_view_likereview`.`review_id`) GROUP BY `temp_view_review`.`review_id` ORDER BY `num_likes` DESC
```

Also if you don't want to order_by on extracted year of date then you can use `F` expressions like this

```
print(Review.objects.filter().annotate(
        num_likes=Count('likereview_review')
    ).annotate(item_count_lag=Window(expression=Lag(expression=F('num_likes')),order_by=[F('date_added')])).order_by('-num_likes').distinct().query)
```

Query for this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT `temp_view_review`.`user_id`, `temp_view_review`.`review_text`, `temp_view_review`.`rating`, `temp_view_review`.`date_added`, `temp_view_review`.`review_id`, COUNT(`temp_view_likereview`.`id`) AS `num_likes`, LAG(COUNT(`temp_view_likereview`.`id`), 1) OVER (ORDER BY `temp_view_review`.`date_added`) AS `item_count_lag` FROM `temp_view_review` LEFT OUTER JOIN `temp_view_likereview` ON (`temp_view_review`.`review_id` = `temp_view_likereview`.`review_id`) GROUP BY `temp_view_review`.`review_id` ORDER BY `num_likes` DESC
```

Comment: Thank you @Deepak Tripathi. +1. Was looking at the same at docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions